# The last 'SetItem' is not saved and clears when the page is Refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, local-storage, setstate

Every time you click on the arrow, the React state is saved in the localٍ storage
But when you refresh the page, the value decreases 1 because the last change is not saved to the localٍ storage

If you modify several items, the problem will be in the last pressed item

`The Code is here` => https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-currying-jb2gx?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling serializing function `setLocalStorage()` before the state is updated with upvote. The setState function is asynchronous and the state updates are batched by React, thus it doesn't change immediately. You should call `setLocalStorage()` inside second parameter (a callback) of setState. Then at the time of calling it you will have correct state.

Like this:

```
upVote = (id, delta) => {
  this.setState(
    (e) => ({
      text: e.text.map((x) =>
        x.id === id ? { ...x, vote: x.vote + delta } : x
      ),
      time: this.state.time
    }),
    () => this.setLocalStorage()
  );
};
```

You could also just pass a function itself as a second parameter of setState:

```
...
   time: this.state.time
    }),
    this.setLocalStorage
  );
}
```